# PHP MySQL PDO - MULTIPLE WHERE AND OR

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display WHERE "remove"(field name) is "No"(value) and multiple search keyword.

so it's only showing value is "No" on "remove" field.
But somehow it's still showing all data includes "Yes" on "remove" field.

Here is my code ....

```
$remove_info = 'No';

        $search_keyword = '';
        if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
            $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
        }

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $table2 
        WHERE `remove` = :remove_info 
        AND `name_first` LIKE :keyword1 
        OR `name_last` LIKE :keyword2 
        OR `birth_date` LIKE :keyword3 
        ORDER BY `fID` DESC ";


    // $limit -- is in pagination code ...


try {
            $query = $sql.$limit;
            $pdo_statement = $db->prepare($query);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':remove_info', '%' . $remove_info . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword1', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword2', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword3', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->execute();
            $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error : Check your error message.";
                file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        }
```

I'm still beginner for PDO, I can't figure it out ....

Would you please tell me what is wrong / where to fix it?

I appreciated your help.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your `OR` conditions with brackets :

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table2 
WHERE `remove` = :remove_info AND 
    (`name_first` LIKE :keyword1 
      OR `name_last` LIKE :keyword2 
      OR `birth_date` LIKE :keyword3) 
  ORDER BY `fID` DESC
```

Because `AND` prior on `OR` and your initial query look like :

```
(`remove` = :remove_info AND `name_first` LIKE :keyword1) OR ...
```

Also, as pointed out by @Toleo (See comments below, Thanks!), you should remove '%' in your `bindValue()` for `:remove_info` because it is not a like condition :

```
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':remove_info', $remove_info, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Haa, beat me to it :)

Comment: Also I don't think that `$remove_info` needs the double **`%`** in the bind.

Comment: @Toleo You're right, I've added it into the answer, thank you!

Comment: Syscall, and Toleo, Thank you very much!!
It works!!  :)